# How to Integrate domain entities from another system

Tags: architecture, system-integration

Given systems A  and B, how can i reference domain entities  from system A in the database of system B, I have this situation at my job and we are replicating the data from system A to B, but it is becoming a nightmare

Ex: System A manages the information of PRODUCT. System B manages SALES of PRODUCTS, so  i have this relationship in system B:  SALE "has many" SALEITEM that "has one" PRODUCT.

Which are the approach for do this type of integration?
Is SOA related to this situation?
Any recommended Reading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What problems are you handling? If this two domains have no intersections than you shouldn't have something to struggle with, it's a normal situation for integration tasks. But if domains intersects then you have some kind of transformations. This is the place where nightmare comes to play. You can redesign one or both domains but the costs! It often doesn't worth the candle especially for legacy systems. I'd suggest to involve a transparent transformation engine at the middleware layer for this purposes.